# Not sure of what to choose between Service, BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Hello guys i am building an app in which i would like to add subscription. That means that every user has to pay monthly.

So i want to check if the user has paid he will be able to proceed with the orders if he didn't then i want a dialog to redirect him to pay. What would you suggest me to use `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `AlarmaManager`?

I was thinking of creating a `Service` and within it create an `AsyncTask` that will check to the database if the user has paid and then if not inform the user with a dialog. Also i was thinking of creating `Notiofications` to the user that the subscription ending.

What is your opinion???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a similar function to check many bills. I combined the three methods to ensure stability. But I think you should use Google Play In-app Billing to achieve subscriptions instead of using a local database. If you must use a database to subscribe:

1.After users subscribe, saved info to the database and start a service. the service start a thread,the thread get Data and Analyzing user payments. then use AlarmManager to set Notification and stopSelf.

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
...
private AlarmManager am;
private PendingIntent pi;
private NotificationManager mNM;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

Thread thread = new Thread(null, mTask, "AlarmService_Service");
    thr.start();

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        List<Subscription> mDataList = getData;

        if (mDataList.size() > 0) {

            for (Subscription mSubscription : mDataList) {


                if (mSubscription.isSub == true) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationService.this,
                            AlamrReceiver.class);
                    intent.putExtra("data", (Serializable)mSubscription);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + uniqueCode));
                    intent.setAction(String.valueOf(uniqueCode));

                    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            NotificationService.this, uniqueCode, intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderTime, pi);
                    uniqueCode = uniqueCode + 1;

                }
            }

        }  

        NotificationService.this.stopSelf();
    }
};
}
```

2.Receive broadcast information and show  Notification.

```
public class AlamrReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private NotificationManager mNM;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mNM = (NotificationManager)       context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Subscription mSubscription = intent.getSerializableExtra("data");

    if (mSubscription != null) {
    showNotification(context, mSubscription);
    }
}
private void showNotification(Context context, Subscription mSubscription) {
    ...
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    builder.setContentTitle(text);
    builder.setContentText(subTitleString + currencyString);
    builder.setSmallIcon(Common.CATEGORY_ICON[cIcon]);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BillDetailsActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(BillDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("dataMap", (Serializable) tMap);

    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    int uniqueRequestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    mNM.notify(uniqueRequestCode, builder.build());

}
```

}

3. Do not forget BOOT_COMPLETED , when the phone restarted , start the service and check the database

Comment: well Google Play In-App Billing is a good choice but since i am doing it locally on my area i think i will try database for subscription

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of concept of your app, but if you want to check whether user has subscribed for current month or not, you don't need to run a `Service` for that.

You should check this in Splash Screen or Main Activity of your app. But anyways,
if you still need to do this, i suggest to go with `Service` or `AlarmManager`.
`BroadcastReceiver` won't work alone, you need to trigger them on particular events according to your need.

Also if you use service, please keep in mind that Android *MIGHT* kill your service in low memory kind of situation.

So i'll suggest that you should go with `AlarmManager`, which will check for subscription status after specific time or something.

PS : i know this should be addded as comment, but i don't have enough reputations to comment so posted as answer

Comment: but is AlarmManager willing to execute AsyncTasks?

Comment: I guess Using Service with AlarmManager will quickly do the thing for u, set up an alarm for specific time, start Subscription checking service, once you get the response, stop the service with stopSelf() method of service.